# Why won't a thread deadlock if it tries to lock the same mutex twice in Linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading

I read about Advanced Programming in Unix Environment 3rd, 11.6.2 Deadlock Avoidance:

> A thread will deadlock itself if it tries to lock the same mutex twice

In order to verify this, I write a demo:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int main() {
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("lock 1\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("lock 2\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    printf("unlock 1\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    printf("unlock 2\n");
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

Main thread didn't blocked, and the output is:

> lock 1
>
> lock 2
>
> unlock 1
>
> unlock 2

Why is it so?

Comment: Perhaps Linux != Unix? Besides, it seems like a reasonable enhancement to prevent a thread from deadlocking itself.

Comment: As a side note, pthreads does support a *recursive mutex* which is the same thing as a regular mutex except it includes logic and a counter so that a thread may lock it more than once without deadlocking (the thread will need to remember to unlock it as many times as it locked it, though).  To make a pthread mutex recursive:    pthread_mutexattr_t mutexattr; pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexattr); pthread_mutexattr_settype(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE); pthread_mutex_init(&_locker, &mutexattr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you compiling this? I suspect you did not pass the -pthread option to the compiler and pthread-related things like the above remain as noops (i.e. they are not pulled in).

I just tested your prog compiled as

> cc -pthread meh.c

and the result nicely hangs after "lock 1".

Comment: You got me!!! I run gcc -pthread myctest.c and then ./a.out, it blocked!!!